# Creating the underscore reduce function from scratch

Tags: javascript, underscore.js, reduce

I am working on creating my own callback functions and higher order function groups.  I am stuck on replicating the underscore reduce function or ._reduce function.  Can someone help me understand how it works underneath the hood it has been a few days for me and I am stumped.  Here is what I have so far.  Please understand I am not utilizing the underscore library, I am trying to replicate it so that I can further my understanding on higher order functions.  Thanks.

```
var reduce = function(collection, iterator, accumulator) {

    var iterator = function(startPoint, combiner){
      for(var i = 0; i <combiner.length; i++){
        startPoint += combiner[i];
    }
    return iterator(accumulator, collection);
}
```

Comment: Well, that's not complete code, and has some issues.  What's your `reduce` function look like right now?

Comment: You're overwriting `iterator`--why? Where is `startPoint` coming from? What is the meaning of the variable `combiner` and why did you name it that way?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In the comments of these answers, there has been a lot of confusion between Underscore's `reduce` and `Array.prototype.reduce`. Two notes:

1. Underscore's `reduce` allows for an empty collection and no seed value. In this case, it will not throw an error but rather returns `undefined`. naomik has convinced me that this is not safe. For example `_([]).reduce(function(a, b) { return a + b});` should either throw an error or return an empty list.
2. Underscore's `reduce` works on both objects and arrays.

Now, to my original post:

---

I actually did the same thing—implement the key functions from Underscore from scratch—a while back, and `reduce` was probably the trickiest. I think `reduce` is easier to grok with a non-functional `reduce` (credit to [naomik](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/29775f933c4d19f3091485c0ea6f4fd2) for this):

```
function reduce(arr, func, seed) {
    var result = seed,
        len = arr.length,
        i = 0;
    for (; i < len; i++) {
        result = func(result, arr[i])
     }
     return result
 }
```

Underscore's implementation is a bit more complex, handling objects and arrays, empty collections, and an optional seed value. It also uses `each` instead of a for loop, since that is more functional in style. This is my implementation of Underscore's `reduce`:

```
var reduce = function(coll, func, seed) {
    // `isEmpty` (not shown) handles empty arrays, strings, and objects.
    // Underscore accepts an optional seed value and does not 
    // throw an error if given an empty collection and no seed.
    if (isEmpty(coll)) {
        return coll;
    }
    var noSeed = arguments.length < 3;

    // `each` (not shown) should treat arrays and objects
    // in the same way.
    each(coll, function(item, i) {
        if (noSeed) {
            // This condition passes at most once. If it passes,
            // this means the user did not provide a seed value.
            // Default to the first item in the list.
            noSeed = false;
            seed = item;
        } else {
            seed = func(seed, item, i);
        }
    });

    return seed;
};
```

Comment: Reduction without an initial value is fundamentally unsafe. It allows you to write bad code.

Comment: I don't understand. Can you provide a scenario where it provides unexpected behavior?

Comment: Say we have a `sum` function that returns the `Number` sum of an array of `Number` values; eg, `sum([1,2,3]) //=> 6`. If we implement `sum` using your `reduce` method and *no* "seed" value, `sum([])` now returns `undefined` which is not a `Number`. Having `sum` implemented this way, we can make no assumptions about its return value. Now, whenever we use it, we'd have to do `var s = sum(arr); if (s === undefined) { console.log('bad sum') } else { console.log(s) }` which is  garbage. If you fail to do this check, you will have made the wrong assumption that `sum` has given you a `Number` result.

Comment: Worse, the `undefined` you get back from `numbers = []; sum(numbers)` isn't the undefined `seed` value, it's the `undefined` from `numbers[0]`. So not only is this reduce function riddled with needless logic and other complexity, it makes the assumption that it's safe to read the first value of a provided array (`numbers` in this case) when the seed value is not provided.

Comment: The result is `reduce` quietly runs behind the scenes of our `sum` function and gives us a value, despite the fact that it's completely useless because it comes with no guarantee. Now the only way we can write "safe" code is to do null/undefined checking everywhere the `reduce` function is used.

Comment: That's not true. My function would return 6. This is because `each` correctly handles iterating over objects and arrays. When no seed is provided, the initial seed is the first element in the array or object, in your example it is 1. See either Underscore's source code for `each` (mine is similar, but dumber): http://underscorejs.org/docs/underscore.html#section-20

Comment: If you're reading closely, I'm criticizing the return value of `sum([])`, not `sum([1,2,3])`. What will your function return for `reduce([], function(x + y) { return x + y })` (where the collection is empty and no seed value is provided)?

Comment: Ahhh, you're right about that! Sorry, I misunderstood, because I thought your issue was with no seed value _per se_. The real issue is that my function should return early if the collection is empty. Nothing to do with seed.

Comment: That is not my precise point, but that's ok. A middle-ground solution would be return immediately if the collection is empty. Or you can throw an Error if the collection is empty and seed is undefined. This is precisely what [Array.prototype.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) does.

Comment: If your precise point is that `reduce` must accept a seed, I am pointing out that that is *not* Underscore's implementation. Why is this even a debate? Go to a website with Underscore and just check: `_.reduce([1,2,3,4], function(a,b){ return a+b})`.

Comment: I don't get your naive, non-functional reduce at all. It fails with an odd number of elements in the input, by the way. *The basic idea is that reduce takes a collection of items and a function and returns a final value by iterating over the collection and combining all the items two at a time using the function.* Actually, this is **NOT** the basic idea. Where did you get that idea?

Comment: If you want more compatibility with native reduce, you should pass the array as the fourth parameter to the callback. You also need to throw an error when the array is empty and no seed is provided.

Comment: I wrote, "It doesn't work for odd-length arrays." Since OP is learning about higher-order functions, I thought an admittedly naive, non-functional example might be useful. And that description is my own. If you can explain why it's wrong, I would love to hear it.

Comment: You can create a naive example that works on arrays of any length.

Comment: I guess by "non-functional" in this case you actually mean "non-functioning".

Comment: As for the error, I already hashed this out with naomik. I implemented Underscore's API, not Array.prototype.reduce's.

Comment: I was trying to be helpful. Provide a better example so I can learn from you?

Comment: @gwg, a naive, imperative reduce could be defined like this: [gist: naive-reduce.js](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/29775f933c4d19f3091485c0ea6f4fd2). Feel free to copy it verbatim, if you'd like.

Comment: @naomik, thank you. That is more clear than my attempt. I've added it and credited you.

Answer (score 5):

A simple recursive function does the trick

```js
// arr - some array of values
// f   - the reducing function
// acc - initial value for the accumulator
function reduce(arr, f, acc) {
  if (arr.length === 0)
    return acc
  else
    return reduce(arr.slice(1), f, f(acc, arr[0]))
}

// --------------------------------------------------
   
// example 1:
// reduce an array of numbers using an adding function

var ex1 = reduce([1,2,3], function(acc, x) { return acc + x }, 0)

console.log(ex1)
//=> 6

// --------------------------------------------------

// example 2:
// reduce an array of pairs to a mapping object

var ex2 = reduce([['a', 1], ['b', 2], ['c', 3]], function(acc, pair) {
  var key = pair[0]
  var value = pair[1]
  acc[key] = value
  return acc
}, {})

console.log(ex2)
//=> { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3 }
```

---

As @torazaburo points out in a comment, if you can use ES6, destructuring assignment cleans up the implementation even more

```
// ES6
function reduce([x, ...xs], f, acc) {
  if (x === undefined)
    return acc
  else
    return reduce(xs, f, f(acc, x))
}
```

Or it gets super sugary sweet with arrow functions

```
// ES6, same as above but using arrow function and ternary expression
const reduce = ([x, ...xs], f, acc)=>
  x === undefined ? acc : reduce(xs, f, f(acc, x))
```

---

The Underscore implementation does provide some other conveniences though I'm guessing these are here to maintain compatibility with native [Array.prototype.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce). I personally wouldn't implement reduce this way, but that's beside the point.

1. Underscore passes an iterator and arr reference to the callback function.
2. Underscore allows you to change the context for the callback function

Here's a revised implementation which supports these other features

```
// our reduce version 2.0
function reduce(collection, iterator, memo, context) {
  function loop(memo, i) {
    if (collection.length === i)
      return memo
    else
      return loop(iterator.call(context, memo, collection[i], i, collection), i + 1)
  }
  return loop(memo, 0)
}
```

You can use it the same as above only now it provides more information to the callback

NOTE

I've purposefully decided **not** to implement a behaviour of Underscore's reduce that allows you to perform a reduction without an initial value. Supporting this behaviour results in unsafe code and should never have made it into Underscore in the first place.

Comment: Odd that downvote me, but then reference Underscore's actual implementation, which allows a user to *not* provide a seed value: http://underscorejs.org/docs/underscore.html#section-22

Comment: If you're referring to the code on the bottom, that is *not* underscore's implementation. That is mine and it does require an initial value.

Comment: I literally link to Underscore's source in my comment. It has a check (f+ctrl for this) `if (arguments.length < 3) { ... }`. It allows no seed.

Comment: You still have not justified your downvote. Reduction without an initial value does not result in undefined behavior. Ashkenas implemented `reduce` with an optional seed. Fogus implemented `reduce` with an optional seed (https://github.com/fogus/lemonad/blob/master/lib/lemonad.js). And of course, `Array.prototype.reduce` implements reduce with an optional seed (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce): `[1,2,3,4].reduce(function(a,b) { return a+b; });`.

Comment: I did remove my downvote after you added the early return for the empty collection condition

Comment: Could be written in slightly more compact form as `function reduce([head, ...tail], f, acc) { return head === undefined ? acc : reduce(tail, f, f(acc, head); }`

Comment: @torazaburo thanks. For simplicity's sake, I decided to leave ES6 out of this one. I added a little note in the middle and attributed it to you ^_^

Answer (score 1):

It's something like it:

```
function reduce(array, combine, start) {
  for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
    start = combine(start, array[i]);
  return start;
}

console.log(reduce([1, 2, 3, 4], function(a, b) {
  return a + b;
}, 0));
```

Link Reference: http://eloquentjavascript.net/05_higher_order.html

Comment: Why are you introducing a new `current` variable?

Comment: It was introduced because  when the start parameter was added to, the `current` variable needs the start value in first iteraction of the loop.

Comment: But you can simply eliminate `current` and just use `start` everywhere you are now using `current`.